# Get DuckDuckGo non-Javascript version in Firefox search bar

Tags: firefox, search, browser-addons, javascript, search-engines

I installed the DuckDuckGo AddOn that adds DuckDuckGo to the list of search engines in Firefox. This is the dropdown list in the upper right just to the left of the search bar that lets you pick which search engine you want to use.

Unfortunately, the AddOn only goes to the Javascript version of DuckDuckGo, not the non-Javascript version (`https://duckduckgo/html`). How can I edit the search engine list entry so that it points to `https://duckduckgo/html` instead of `https://duckduckgo` ?

Comment: Is there a reason for installing the add-on instead of visiting https://duckduckgo.com/html and adding it "manually" to the list of search engines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [official HTML version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duckduckgo-html/) is available too:

> DuckDuckGo is a search engine that does not track you. Adds DuckDuckGo (non-JS HTML version) to the search bar.
>
> <sub>Source: [DuckDuckGo (HTML SSL)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duckduckgo-html/)</sub>

Comment: The extension is not available anymore (firefox esr 68.4.2)